# Facebook Login using Jmeter

Tags: regex, facebook, jmeter

I want to do a load test my Heroku application using Jmeter.
To access the functionality of the application, I need to login through Facebook first. 
I tried with browser recording using proxy server. But the problem is the code parameter  (response_type) returned by facebook  is hard coded in the callback URI. So its giving exception (Code expired exception) while running the Jmeter script.

I am able to view the code in response header of `https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request` URL. So I need to grab this code from this header dynamically and put in the code parameter of callback URL.

For this I am using **Regular Expression Extractor** in Jmeter under `/dialog/permissions.request` URL.

My response header looks like below:

```
Cache-Control   private, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Date            Wed, 26 Dec 2012 13:37:17 GMT
Expires         Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT
Location        http://myapplication.herokuapp.com/oauth/authenticate/facebook?code=SOME-CODE
P3P CP="Facebook does not have a P3P policy. Learn why here: http://fb.me/p3p"
```

I want to extract this `code=some code` and put it in the next URL using regular expression extractor.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the JMeter context, but the regex can be something like:

```
\?code=(.*)
```

You might need to double the backslash. The `$` can be problematic if the header is checked as a whole, you can replace it with `\n` perhaps.

[EDIT] I found the [tester](http://jakarta.apache.org/oro/demo.html) pointed from the [JMeter page](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html) and used it against the header content you gave. Apparently the `$` was not necessary, the search is stopping on a line bound. Still not sure about doubling the backslash. Experiment.

Comment: I tried with Regex. But it is not able to extract the parameter from **location** header. I need to fetch the **code** parameter from Location header. I tried with both **Redirect automatically**  and **Follows redirect**  options in Jmeter. Still it does not work. Could you please help?

Comment: Have you tried the variations I was suggesting? I removed the `$` but I am still not too sure about \? vs. \\? You have to try both...

Answer (score 0):

Problem is not with Regular Expression Extractor as mentioned by Saswat Sahoo. Main problem is Location header not even getting in Response header of Jmeter. We can see Location header in Browser's response header. Few information are missing in Jmeter Response Header compared to Browser's response header.