# Jmeter Oauth Plugin for Facebook Login

Tags: facebook, jmeter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook Login using Jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041488/facebook-login-using-jmeter)

I am trying [Oauth Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/downloads/list) in Jmeter to login into facebook. 
I used Facebook's Api Key as Consumer key and Api Secret as Consumer Secret inOauth request Sampler. But I am not able to retrieve the Oauth Token and Oauth Secret from this.

Server name I used : **facebook.com** and path : **dialog/permission.request**

Please Help!!

Comment: You already asked here and did not give feedback: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041488/facebook-login-using-jmeter

Answer (score 0):

We are trying to use jmeter for an app that uses fb login.

Two method we are trying to get code value generated from Facebook

1) Extracting code using Regular Expression Extractor - We were trying to extract the code value using Regular expression Extractor and redirect from fb to application with code as parameter anticipating that code value present in jmeter scripts response header. I had compared request / response between Jmeter scripts and browser’s using firebug on Firefox, where I could see few information missing in scripts from that of browser, like Location(which has code value) in response header of scripts.

2) JMeter oauth plugin for facebook login - we don't know configuration details in jmeter to access Facebook login. Please refer more details on oauth on http://code.google.com/p/oauth/downloads/list.